# How to allow touches in React Native when a ScrollView is scrolling?

Tags: events, scroll, react-native, scrollview

Given a View in React Native that renders a ScrollView with multiple TouchableHighlight controls, how can touches on a TouchableHighlight be allowed if the user has initiated a scroll ( contents within the ScrollView are in motion )?

Currently, the touch is handled by the ScrollView and is considered a "stop event" wherein the ScrollView stops its scrolling operation.  Which is natural since that's a common way in which users stop a scroll in progress.  However I'd like to be able to change this behavior and allow and/or detect the touch event while the ScrollView content is in motion.

Comment: Have you tried setting keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} in the ScrollView?  I know it allows touches to pass through to TouchableHighlight, not sure how it behaves while scrolling is "in motion"

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution for that, as far as I know. [You may try to set the `onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture` property on the ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#capture-shouldset-handlers), that may work.

Comment: I set `onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={() => false}`. It didn't change a thing