# TouchableHighlight in the rows of a SectionList/Flatlist not clickable while scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

We have a SectionList with rows that are wrapped with the TouchableHighlight tag. When the user scrolls he is not able to click on a row until the SectionList comes to a full stop. This leads to a UX feeling of a delayed click. We would like to make the TouchableHighlight clickable even while scrolling. Any option to get around this?

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.rowClick}
                               onPress={props.onPress}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
              ...
        </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: All the lists use a `ScrollView` underneath and this is happening because the `ScrollView` is capturing the first touch as a stop event. [See this same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415474/how-to-allow-touches-in-react-native-when-a-scrollview-is-scrolling) I can't provide an answer having never used this, but you'll want to look into the [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) docs.